# how to clear the session if the system closed

Tags: php, yii

If used yii session in my website for member login . If i shutdown the system without logout my session, the session maintenance upto the next day. How to clear my session .

In my config file . i have the following code.

**config code :**-

```
       return array(
        'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'name'=>'sitename',
        'sourceLanguage' => 'sys',
        'language' => 'en',
        'preload'=>array('log', 'PreloadCms'),

        'import'=>array(
            'application.models.*',
            'application.components.*', 
            'application.modules.user.models.*',
            'application.modules.user.components.*',
            'application.extensions.easyimage.EasyImage',
            'zii.behaviors.*',      
        ),

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'admin',
            ) 
        ) + require(dirname(__FILE__).'/modules.php')
        ,

        'components'=>array(
            'PreloadCms' => array (
            'class' => 'application.modules.cms_core.components.PreloadCms',
            ),  

            'user'=>array(
                'class' => 'WebUser',
                'allowAutoLogin'=>false,
            ),
        )   

);
```

Then i set the **session here :**-

```
 public function authenticate()  
{
    $user=Signup::model()->findByAttributes(array('varEmail'=>$this->username));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if($user->varPassword!=$this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
         $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
         $this->_id=$user->intId; 
         Yii::app()->session['id']=$user->intId;
          $this->username=$user->varEmail; 
       }   
    return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you log in the user in the authenticate method it's not quite right, better use a another method to set the session, like in default yii LoginForm.

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate(); // Authenticate just checks if a user exists.
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // Set here the session life.
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration); // Use this method to proper login the user
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

For more details check this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

Make sure to follow the correct yii patterns and not to reinvent the wheel.